# Bootstrap Navbar Collapsed Dropdown Submenu

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that looks pretty good on pc. 
Unfortunately I have a problem with navigation when working on mobile devices. The navigation has a submenu containing two subitems ( language to choose ). If I use the website on the pc ( big displays ), then the submenu is displayed correctly. However, when I look at the mobile device, I only see the drop-down menu item "Language" but not the submenu that should open when I click on it.

Now I want to do two things. 
When I open the navigation, the size of the submenu should cover the whole display. Thats easy with "height: 100 vh".

secondly ( the most important ), the subitems in the dropdown should generally be displayed. But I couln't make it at all.

Here is the webpage:

// removed because solved

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to link my website ... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the following styles it will solve your problem

you have to remove the `max-height` that you defined which is `max-height: 200px`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
ul#nav {
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

and also you have to remove display:none from

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
ul#nav li ul {
    /* display: none; */
}
```

because the **collapse** won't work if you left the `display:none`;

Comment: let me see.. I will try that

Comment: could you tell me where you found the: ul#nav li ul { display: none } code?

Comment: I've found it :) the responsive.css :) Thanks mate !